# I have a problem with carousel dynamic items when a use splice function to delete item

Tags: c#, angular, carousel

when a use the splice function to delete item(image) they delete all the images.

```
 when i delete the item  I want the carousel show the others images not disappear.
<div id="carouselExampleControls " class="carousel slide "
 data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" >

    <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let img of urls; let i = index;
    let isFirst = first" [ngClass]="{active:isFirst}"
    >

      <img  [src]="img" >

      <div class="carousel-caption d-non "
       >

<button type="button" (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)" 
class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >
<img src="../assets/images/delete_delete_exit_1577.png"
           style="width: 20px;" /></button>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

`removeSelectedFile(index)
   { 
    this.urls.splice(index, 1);
     } `
```

when i delete the item  I want the carousel show the others images not disappear.
thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.urls = this.urls.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: That would keep only the image that he wants to delete. As mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), `splice` removes items from the original array and returns the removed items.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.